# HTML: Image with absolute position, text flow over. How to do it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify a code not written by me, so I want to modify only what's necessary, to not mess up with an entire site.

I want to achieve this
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/examples/positioning1.html

but with the image in the back, instead of being in front of text.

How can I do it without using position:absolute on text?

(source:http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/stylesheets/csslayout.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `z-index`

`z-index:1;` to the image

`z-index:2;` to the text-div

Comment: It's not working. Maybe z-index are to be used somewhere else?

Comment: @Andres could you post up some code so I can give it a try please?

Comment: Ok, it seems to work if I add 'position:relative' beside 'z-index' to the text. Just tell me if there exist a better way to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: `position:relative;` is the default, this should have no effect on this? Did you have `position:absolute;` in before?

Comment: it's because z-index is ignored in elements that do not have the position attribute explicitly set. 
So although relative is the default unless added to the css the z-index will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trying to set a background image.  In that case you need to use something like

```
body {
  background-image: url("http://yoursite.com/images/image_name.gif");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Is a sort of background, but inserted as an image and fixed at the bottom of the site. Problem is that I can't select text under the image or click any textual link under it. My site is www.optness.com and the image is at the bottom, the OO semitransparent image.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work if I add 'position:relative' beside 'z-index' to the text. Just tell me if there exist a better way to solve it. Thanks!